# Invocar funciones dentro de un arreglo

Tags: javascript, array, function

tengo una duda que no logro entender, como se puede insertar/invocar una función dentro de un arreglo?

Ya intente de todo y nada me funciona.

El problema es que no se puede usar export ni required.

Ya probe con push, con concat y con unshift

Este sería lo que e probado

```js
function setPropsOnArr(array = []) {

    const hola = function () {
        return 'Hola!'
    }
    const doble = function (num) {
        return num * 2
    }
    const river = function () {
        return 'plate'
    }

    let arrFinal = array.concat(5, hola, doble, river)

    return arrFinal
}

console.log(setPropsOnArr());


aca empieza el problema
```

```js
describe('Propiedades de un Objeto de tipo Arreglo', function() {
  var array;

  beforeEach(function() {
    array = [];
    setPropsOnArr(array);
  });

  describe('Función `setPropsOnArr`', function() {
    it('agrega la propiedad `hola` con una función que devuelva `Hola!`', function() {
      expect(array.hola()).toEqual('Hola!');
    });

    it('agrega la propiedad `river` con referencia a `plate`', function() {
      // También podemos acceder a las propiedades con bracket-notation sin problema.
      expect(array['river']).toEqual('plate');
    });

    it('accede al indice `0` del Arreglo', function() {
      expect(array[0]).toEqual(5);
    });

    it('agrega la propiedad `doble` con la función que duplique el parámetro ingresado', function() {
      expect(array.doble(4)).toEqual(8);
      expect(array['doble'](123)).toEqual(246);
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: Puedes describir un poco mas que es lo que quieres lograr, hacer un array y que cada elemento sea una funcion que puedas llamar?

Comment: Si, lo que quiero hacer es crear un arreglo para después invocar las funciones en testem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que tu problema está en que el array que generas tiene índices numéricos y luego quieres acceder a la función por su nombre el cual no existe, por ejemplo `array['river']`.

Si te fijas, la salida de tu primer código arroja lo siguiente:

```
[
  5, function () {
        return 'Hola!'
    }, function (num) {
        return num * 2
    }, function () {
        return 'plate'
    }
]
```

Como ves, no existe "river" en el arreglo, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
function setPropsOnArr(array = []) {
   return {
      0: 5,
      "hola" :  function () {
          return 'Hola!'
      },
      "doble" : function (num) {
          return num * 2
      },
      "river" : function () {
          return 'plate'
       }
   };
}

let array = setPropsOnArr();

console.log(array); //muestra el objeto resultante

console.log("PRUEBAS");

console.log(array.hola()); //función hola
console.log(array['river'] ); //implementación función river
console.log(array['river']() ); //resultado  función river
console.log(array[0]);
console.log(array.doble(4));
console.log(array['doble'](123));
```

Answer (score 2):

Cada elemento en un array se almacena como una variable o una funcion ejecutable

```
function agregarElementos(array = []) {
    const myFuncion1 = function () {
        console.log("prueba funcion 1");
    }
    const myFuncion2 = function (param) {
        console.log("prueba funcion 2: ", param);
    }
    array.push(myFuncion1);
    array.push(myFuncion2);
    return array;
}

var myArray = [
    function() { console.log("func1");}
];

myArray = agregarElementos(myArray);

myArray[0](); // Consola: func1
myArray[1](); // Consola: prueba funcion 1
myArray[2]("SO"); // Consola: prueba funcion 2: SO

// O un objeto (key: value)

function agregarElementos(array = {}) {
    const myFuncion1 = function () {
        console.log("prueba funcion 1");
    }
    const myFuncion2 = function (param) {
        console.log("prueba funcion 2: ", param);
    }
    array.ejecutar1 = myFuncion1;
    array.ejecutar2 = myFuncion2;
    return array;
}

var myArray = {};

myArray = agregarElementos(myArray);

myArray.ejecutar1(); // Consola: prueba funcion 1
myArray.ejecutar2("SO"); // Consola: prueba funcion 2: SO
```